# Photoshop always prompts me with a Save As dialog when saving

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When press the key combination Ctrl + S Photoshop goes to the Save As dialog. I'm trying to save a PNG image, but Photoshop wants me to Save (it) As a PSD format. Any suggestions?

Comment: I believe this questions belongs on [SU].

Comment: Oops, my mistake; I did not know of any other place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Photoshop layers are not supported by PNG. When you save out as a PNG, your layers are flattened, keeping you from editing them in the future.

If you are working with layers, and simply trying to SAVE, Photoshop is trying to prevent you from losing your layers when saving as a PNG, thus forcing you to choose a format each time.

The best solution would be save a "master" copy of your document as a PSD, making whatever changes you need. Once complete, do one last save of the "master" PSD, then depending on how you plan on using the PNG, do a "Save for Web & Devices" or simply a "Save As..." a PNG.

If you decide to make changes in the future, open the PSD make your changes, and then save it again as a PNG.

If you plan on using the PNG on websites or inside applications, it is best to use "Save for Web & Devices" as you will have more control over the final file size, giving you the best quality image at the lowest file size.

Comment: Much appreciated, although I found this out myself just today.

Answer (score 0):

Try to press SHIFT+ALT+Command and S if you're working on a Mac, if not use CTRL instead of Command. Then choose your format in the top right corner. PNG is used for web and the short command means that you want to say the file for Web. I would also save a PSD file for a backup if you want to do some other fixes in your images after you saved it as a PNG.

Comment: I am working on a PC with Windows 7 so that isn't going to work, but isn't there a like a check box I could check to enable overriding files with the same name?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and here is how I solved it!
In my case I had cropped the image with the option “Delete Cropped Pixels” **unticked** (unchecked).

So, those extra pixels that were not "lost" were forcing me to “Save as” PSD; that's why I was always getting the “Save as...” dialog
when choosing “File” → “Save”
or pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

The solution is:

- Choose the “Crop” tool
- Tick-ON (check) the “Delete Cropped Pixels” checkbox

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I know the question is old and may be answered, but maybe it can help future help-seekers :)